# Room @Insert lets Entity empty Android

Tags: android, android-room

When I try to insert values in some tables of my DB, mainly it is when I try to insertAll into the GSOEntity. Mainly, I have a table GSOEntity:

public class GSOEntity {

```
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.GSO.ID_SOCIETE)
private long idSociete;

@ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.GSO.LIBELLE)
private String libelle;

@ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.GSO.AUTORISATION)
private int autorisation;

public GSOEntity(long idSociete, String libelle, int autorisation) {
    this.idSociete = idSociete;
    this.libelle = libelle;
    this.autorisation = autorisation;
}

public long getIdSociete() {
    return idSociete;
}

public void setIdSociete(long idSociete) {
    this.idSociete = idSociete;
}

public String getLibelle() {
    return libelle;
}

public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
    this.libelle = libelle;
}

public int getAutorisation() {
    return autorisation;
}

public void setAutorisation(int autorisation) {
    this.autorisation = autorisation;
}
}
```

Here it is my DB Class:

```
@Database(entities = {CCREntity.class, ConfigEntity.class, GRAEntity.class, GREEntity.class, GSOEntity.class, GTCEntity.class, LGCEntity.class,
        LNCEntity.class, PRFEntity.class, PRVEntity.class, PSCEntity.class, TAREntity.class, TLIEntity.class, XPCEntity.class}, version = DBConstants.DB_VERSION, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class ParamsManager extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract CCRDao ccrDao();

public abstract ConfigDao configDao();

public abstract GRADao graDao();

public abstract GREDao greDao();

public abstract GSODao gsoDao();

public abstract GTCDao gtcDao();

public abstract LGCDao lgcDao();

public abstract LNCDao lncDao();

public abstract PRFDao prfDao();

public abstract PRVDao prvDao();

public abstract PSCDao pscDao();

public abstract TARDao tarDao();

public abstract TLIDao tliDao();

public abstract XPCDao xpcDao();
```

This is my GSODao:

```
@Dao
public interface GSODao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBConstants.GSO.TABLE_NAME)
List<GSOEntity> findAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBConstants.GSO.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBConstants.GSO.ID_SOCIETE + " = :idSociete")
GSOEntity find(int idSociete);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
long insert(@NonNull GSOEntity entity);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
long[] insertAll(@NonNull List<GSOEntity> entities);

@Query("DELETE FROM " + DBConstants.GSO.TABLE_NAME)
public void deleteAll();
```

When I do:

```
ParamsManager paramsManager = Room.databaseBuilder(context, ParamsManager.class, DBConstants.DB_NAME).build();

        List<GSOEntity> insertList = new ArrayList<>();
        insertList.add(new GSOEntity(1, "++¿ ", 2));
        insertList.add(new GSOEntity(2, "++¿ ", 2));
        insertList.add(new GSOEntity(3, "++¿ ", 1));

        long[] data = paramsManager.gsoDao().insertAll(insertList);

        Log.wtf(TAG, "TRY1 " + data);

        List<GSOEntity> insertList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        insertList2.add(new GSOEntity(4, "Normal1", 2));
        insertList2.add(new GSOEntity(5, "Normal2", 2));
        insertList2.add(new GSOEntity(6, " Norm al3 ", 1));

        long[] data2 = paramsManager.gsoDao().insertAll(insertList2);
        Log.wtf(TAG, "TRY 2 " + data2);
```

After I extract the DB from my phone, and I see that the GSO Table is....empty!!
I removed all calls to "deleteAll" and so on. I even tried to completely extract this part of code to be the ONLY one to be executed, and anyway, the same result.....Table is empty.
Anyone has the same problem??

I am using

> ```
> compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha3'
> annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha3'
> ```

I also tried using

> ```
> compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
> annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
> ```

Thanks